# Emacs spellcheck tool for comments in c/c++ code

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs as my text editor for c/c++ code. Is there any tool which spell check comments for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flyspell](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Spelling.html) does in-line spell checking and highlights incorrect words as you type. Just make sure you activate `flyspell-prog-mode` to spell-check only the comments (instead of `flyspell-mode`, which checks the whole text, and will get lost in your source code).

After you activate `flyspell` only newly typed text is spell-checked. You have to run `flyspell-buffer` to check existing text. I have the following in my initialization file to automatically do this:

```
(defun my/flyspell-buffer-after-activation ()
  "Run `flyspell-buffer' after `flyspell-mode' is activated."
  (when flyspell-mode
    (flyspell-buffer)))

(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'my/flyspell-buffer-after-activation)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i have existing code, how can I spell check comments with flyspell?

Comment: You have to run `flyspell-buffer`. See my edit on how to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<META-x> ispell-comments-and-strings`.  It does what it says.